# Woocommerce get product by custom query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

This is based on WordPress and WooCommerce and dealing in post and post_meta table

I have to get all the product ID which has a meta_key = "_shop" and meta_value = "yes"

Typical Condition:

If the meta key and the meta value is matched with the parent product then its all variation must also include.

If the meta key and the meta value is not marched with the parent but its variation has meta key and meta value matched return the variation only.

```
Product(#18)(simple):           _shop = 'yes'
Product(#19)(variable):         _shop = 'yes' (Parent is Yes)
       Product(#20)(variation): _shop = 'yes'
       Product(#21)(variation): _shop = 'no'
       Product(#22)(variation): _shop = 'no'
Product(#23)(simple):           _shop = 'yes'
Product(#24)(variable):         _shop = 'no'  (parent is no)
       Product(#25)(variation): _shop = 'no'
       Product(#26)(variation): _shop = 'yes' (Only this variation)
       Product(#20)(variation): _shop = 'no'
```

IDS I Need:

> ## #18 #19 #20 #21 #22 #23 #26

Comment: On what basis do you identify the parent for a variation? Like #25 parent's is #24?

Answer (score 0):

```
    select  productID from your_table
   where meta_key = "_shop" and meta_value = "yes"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But there are two typical conditions are there.

Comment: can you clear a little bit more about typical condition

Comment: Okay. It is based on WordPress and WooCommerce. Get all the product ID which has the meta key = 'shop' and meta value = 'yes'. If the product type is variable check for its meta key and value matches,then return all variations under that.

Comment: that means condition is if product type=variable and meta key = 'shop' and meta value = 'yes' then return all product id

Comment: Yes. Return all its variations and if parent is not matches check for its variation and if variation matches return the ID of the variation

Comment: then add product type also in where condition

Comment: @GowthamGanesan have you checked?

Comment: Yes, But no luck.

Comment: I think we have a gap to know the condition can you please share whole data set and details condition with output sample

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('init',function(){
    global $wpdb;
    $ids = $wpdb->get_results("
                                SELECT p.ID as id 
                                From $wpdb->posts as p
                                LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta as m
                                ON p.ID = m.post_id
                                WHERE m.meta_key = '_shop'
                                AND m.meta_value = 'yes'
                                AND p.post_type = 'product' OR p.post_type = 'product_variation'
                            ");
    if(!empty($ids)){
        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            echo $id->id;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. There are two cases if parent product matches the scenario return all variations otherwise return only the variations